# Why Eclipse deletes a reference to the function?

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

I tried to call the method `.getHours()` and Eclipse marks the name of a function with a line.

Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: This means that the method has been marked with a `@Deprecated` annotation. You can click into the definition of the method to verify that, but [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours%28%29) is the documentation to be explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is deprecated, e.g., annotated with `@Deprecated`.

It means you *probably* shouldn't be using it, since support may disappear in the future.

Comment: I interpret depricated to mean there's a better design to use.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator That's a non-standard interpretation. "Deprecated" means it should be avoided, and that the library/code maintainer wishes the feature to not be used. Deprecated functionality is sometimes removed in major releases. In Java-the-language it's unlikely deprecated functionality will be removed because of Java's slavish adherence to backward compatibility, but that's not the general rule.

Comment: What's non-standard about [Java's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html)? "A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists."

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Nothing--but you focus on the last one, and convention tends towards the former. If you look across open source Java projects, deprecated things are often removed (that's dangerous) during upgrade releases. It's not *just* that there's a "better option", it's *DO NOT USE THIS*.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. You're talking about a [*De facto* standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto_standard), which I admit I don't have the experience (in open-source projects over time) to dispute.

Answer (score 1):

That mark means that the method has been deprecated. This means the author of the code intends you to avoid that method, but doesn't remove it because of compatibility.

If you check the javadoc is possible the author has left documented an alternative way to perform the behavior.